# How to calculate checksum for Modbus RTU with PyCRC

Tags: python, modbus, crc

I'm writing a python application that will handle Modbus RTU commands.
I am trying to calculate the CRC using PyCRC 'CRC16(modbus_flag=True)', however I don't seem to be able to get the correct value out compared to the value in example frames I've tested from various sources.

I'm new to modbus so perhaps I'm missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Basic code that doesn't seem to give expected results:

```
from PyCRC.CRC16 import CRC16

def checksum(restOfFrame):
    return CRC16(modbus_flag=True).calculate(restOfFrame.encode())  

print(hex(checksum('110100130025')))
# gives 5992, should give 0E84? (based on example frame '11 01 0013 0025 0E84')
```

Comment: You would need to calculate the checksum from the actual bytes of the frame, rather than a hexadecimal representation of those bytes.  `binascii.unhexlify()` would be one way to perform that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you need to provide the bytes, not their hexadecimal representation. If you give it `b'\x11\x01\x00\x13\x00\x25'` instead, you'll get `840e`. Also note that the CRC is stored in the stream in little-endian order, not big-endian. So your expecation for the CRC was incorrect.